# pgpool :no such file or directory pgpool.pid

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I have installed pg-pool 2 using their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pgpool/pgpool2.git)
When I use the command:

```
pgpool -n &
```

I am getting the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create a folder pgpool in the /var/run directory

```
cd /var/run
sudo mkdir pgpool
```

and then give write rights to the directory:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx pgpool`
```

Then run pgpool using:

```
sudo pgpool -n &
```